# BytesIO replaces transparency in PNG files with black background

Tags: python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library, urllib, bytesio

I want to keep transparent background at my 'image' variable.

If I write into a file, image looks fine. I mean image has a transparent background.

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as response:
     imgdata = response.read()
     with open("temp_png_file.png", "wb") as output:
         output.write(imgdata)
```

However, if I keep the image data in BytesIO, transparent background becomes a black background.

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as response:
     imgdata = response.read()
ioFile = io.BytesIO(imgdata) 
img = Image.open(ioFile)
img.show()
```

(Above code piece, img.show line shows an image with black background.)

How can I keep a transparent image object in img variable ?

Comment: Try changing `img = Image.open(ioFile)` to `img = Image.open(ioFile).convert('RGBA')`

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thank you mark ! It is the solution for this question. However, I stuck at my next step as well. I need to convert this into OpenCV image object. I did this : "opencvImage = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)" 
And, opencvImage shows a black background as well.. Do you have any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: Your image is RGBA after `convert('RGBA')`, so you need to decide how you want to handle transparency. OpenCV's `imshow()` doesn't handle transparency, so it will look wrong there but if you write it to a file it will be fine. PIL/Pillow offers a `show()` method that does understand transparency, so you can do `from PIL import Image` and then `Image.fromarray(numpyImage).show()` where `numpyimage` is an OpenCV image or Numpy ndarray.

Comment: Thank you @MarkSetchell. Reply the question, thus I can mark as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things...

---

Firstly, if you want and expect an RGBA image when opening a file with `Pillow`, it is best to convert whatever you get into that - else you may end up trying to display palette indices instead of RGB values:

So change this:

```
img = Image.open(ioFile)
```

to this:

```
img = Image.open(ioFile).convert('RGBA')
```

---

Secondly, **OpenCV**'s `imshow()` can't handle transparency, so I tend to use **Pillow**'s `show()` method instead. Like this:

```
from PIL import Image

# Do OpenCV stuff
...
...

# Now make OpenCV array into Pillow Image and display
Image.fromarray(numpyImage).show()
```